# I can't figure out why part of my program is looping 4 times before moving on to the next statements

Tags: java, methods, return, arguments, void

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        getWidth();
        getLength();
        getArea();
        displayData();
    }
        public static double getWidth()
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the width of the rectangle: ");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            double width = keyboard.nextDouble();
            return width;
        }

        public static double getLength()
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the length of the rectangle: ");
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            double length = keyboard.nextDouble();
            return length;
        }

        public static double getArea()
        {
            double area = getWidth() * getLength();
            return area;
        }
        public static void displayData()
        {
            System.out.println("Width: " + getWidth() +
                               "\nLength: " + getLength() +
                               "\nArea: " + getArea());
        }

}
```

Results:

> Enter the width of the rectangle: 3
>
> Enter the length of the rectangle: 4
>
> Enter the width of the rectangle: 3
>
> Enter the length of the rectangle: 4
>
> Enter the width of the rectangle: 3
>
> Enter the length of the rectangle: 4
>
> Enter the width of the rectangle: 3
>
> Enter the length of the rectangle: 4
>
> Width: 3.0
>
> Length: 4.0
>
> Area: 12.0

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are calling `getWidth()` and `getLength()` four times.

Once from `main`, 

once from `getArea`, 

once from `displayData` (which again calls `getArea`)

Each call to `getWidth()` and `getLength()` promts data from `System.in`. You must

1. Get length and width once and store it (in an instance variable maybe)
2. Subsequently read/fetch from where you have stored them.

Comment: How would I do it though? I tried storing it in main but can't figure out how to call it from other methods

Comment: I would suggest you to create a separate class to hold these values. If not make them `static` so that you can access from `displayData` (in class Main)

Answer (score 0):

Try only calling displayData() in main and remove the other calls.
The problem is that displayData() itself calls the other methods again.